# PHP function giving Undefined offset notice

Tags: php

I have a PHP function that returns the number of views on an article in thousands. For example, an article with 1240 views will be shown as 1.2k

The function I am using for this is working perfectly. This is the function:

```
function kconvert($num) {
  $x = round($num);
  $x_number_format = number_format($x);
  $x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
  $x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
  $x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
  $x_display = $x;
  $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');   <-- line 78
  $x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1]; <!-- line 79
  return $x_display;
};
```

The problem is that every time this function is executed, so on every page load, this writes a PHP notice to the error_log:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in xxx/functions.php on line 78
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: -1 in xxx/functions.php on line 79
```

I highlighted the line numbers in the function above.

Is there any way to make sure this function is not giving a PHP notice every time it loads? Thanks!

Comment: What is !== doing here?

Comment: Do you mean to say that under the correct circumstances, the function works and does not emit a notice? If that is the case, then you need logic to prevent it from being called when circumstances are not correct (its input `$num` is incomplete or not a number or unset). Post the code that _calls_ the function please/

Comment: Jon, actually I did. I'm sorry.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski the function is working perfectly. In my article, I use: `kconvert($views)` to return the views in the correct format. This is working just like it's supposed and the page is loading fine. The problem is that it writes a notice to the error_log everytime, when I want my error_log to be as empty as possible

Comment: It seems like there is only a single element in $x_array, which makes $x_array[1] and invalid index and would also result in count($x_array) - 1 - 1 = -1, which you are seeing in line 79.  What number are you getting for $x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only test if the number is less than 1000, that is where the error occurs

```
function kconvert($num) {
  $x = round($num);
  if($num >= 1000){
      $x_number_format = number_format($x);
      $x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
      $x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
      $x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
      echo $x_count_parts;
      $x_display = $x;
      $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : ''); 
      $x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1];
      return $x_display;
  }else{
      return $num;
  }
};
```

Comment: Indeed, although I suppose the OP should test the input number before trying to "cast" its format. If even for small numbers you want to display thousands, you should do something like `if (strlen($x_number_format) <= 3) $x_number_format = '0,' . $x_number_format;` (i.e. some kind of leading zero), just after computing `$x_number_format`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function kconvert($num) {
  $x = round($num);
  $x_number_format = number_format($x);
  $x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
  $x_display = $x;
  if (count($x_array) > 1) {
    $x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
    $x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
    $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');
    $x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1];
  }
  return $x_display;
};
```